# Array to string conversion on wp-class

Tags: php, wordpress

**in wordpress :**

my input

```
<input name='pb[1][title]' value='mytitle'>
```

for update:

```
update_option('ED_options_pb',$_POST['pb']);
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in G:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp.php on line 281

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_POST['pb'][1]['title']` since the name of the input element is `pb[1][title]`.